# When I try to signout from GoogleApiClient I got Error message GoogleApiClient.isConnected() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-plus, google-api-client

When I try to sign out from `GoogleApiClient` I got the following error message

```
GoogleApiClient.isConnected() on a null object reference
```

Here is my code:

```
public static GoogleSignInOptions gso;
public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

//.........

google.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext()).enableAutoManage(getActivity(), new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();
            Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();


            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"User Name "+ acc.getDisplayName()+ "Mail  "+acc.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

and my sign out code

```
  public void signout(){
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(),LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
```

And I also tried:

```
if (UserLogin.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    UserLogin.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: post your code mGoogleApiClient define and initialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Define:

```
public GoogleSignInOptions gso;
public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
```

Initialize in Oncreate method:

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();
  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Now set click listener on signIn button

```
google.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"User Name "+ acc.getDisplayName()+ "Mail  "+acc.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

/////

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

//Sign out

```
private void signOut() {
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
             Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(),LoginActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent1);
             getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
}
```

Hope this will help you.